# Erro de sintaxe de SQL em uma aplicação Flask

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, flask

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de exibição de jogos, com login de usuário necessário para poder adicionar jogos a essa lista, mas quando tento fazer executar a query, recebo um erro de sintaxe.

Segue o código que prepara o banco de dados (tem o principal da aplicação web, ainda por alterar, e o DAO de "Jogo" e de "Usuário" também.):

```py
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
print('Conectando...')
conn = pymysql.connect(user='root', passwd='admin', host='127.0.0.1', port=3306)

criar_tabelas = '''SET NAMES utf8;
    CREATE DATABASE jogoteca;
    USE jogoteca;
    CREATE TABLE jogo (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      nome varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      categoria varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      console varchar(20) NOT NULL
    ); ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
    CREATE TABLE usuario (
      id varchar(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COLLATE utf8_bin,
      nome varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      senha varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL

    ); ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;'''

conn.cursor().execute(criar_tabelas)

# inserindo usuarios
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany(
      'INSERT INTO jogoteca.usuario (id, nome, senha) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
      [
            ('andré', 'André Jurgen', 'flask'),
            ('miguel', 'Miguel de Cervantes', '12345'),
            ('danilo', 'Danilo Ravetti', 'python')
      ])

cursor.execute('select * from jogoteca.usuario')
print(' -------------  Usuários:  -------------')
for user in cursor.fetchall():
    print(user[1])

# inserindo jogos
cursor.executemany(
      'INSERT INTO jogoteca.jogo (nome, categoria, console) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
      [
            ('God of War 4', 'Ação', 'PS4'),
            ('NBA 2k18', 'Esporte', 'Xbox One'),
            ('Rayman Legends', 'Indie', 'PS4'),
            ('Super Mario RPG', 'RPG', 'SNES'),
            ('Super Mario Kart', 'Corrida', 'SNES'),
            ('Fire Emblem Echoes', 'Estratégia', '3DS'),
      ])

cursor.execute('select * from jogoteca.jogo')
print(' -------------  Jogos:  -------------')
for jogo in cursor.fetchall():
    print(jogo[1])

# commitando senão nada tem efeito
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

O erro que tenho é:

```
"C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/jogoteca/prepara_banco.py"
Conectando...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/jogoteca/prepara_banco.py", line 22, in <module>
    conn.cursor().execute(criar_tabelas)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE jogoteca;\n    USE jogoteca;\n    CREATE TABLE jogo (\n      id int' at line 2")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?
Grato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O fato de você poder criar uma string de tamanho arbitrário em Python, com `"""`, ão significa que você pode colocar quantos comandos de SQL lá dentro e te-los executados como se tivessem sido digitados direto no prompt do banco de dados:

A chamada `.execute()` de qualquer conector de banco de dados do Python executa **um único comando** (statement) em SQL - inclusive não se pode colocar o `;` ao final do comando.

Por isso o erro: o `;`, quando digitado direto no prompt do banco de dados sinaliza o final do comando. Para chamadas programáticas a um banco SQL (a qualquer banco SQL_, o que sinaliza o final do comando é o final da string. (Essa característica sozinha já dificulta ataques de SQL injection - embora não impeça se outras partes do código derem brecha - mas só ataques feitos como subqueries, não como queries separadas).

A solução no caso é colocar cada comando que você deseja executar no SQL em uma string separada, e fazer uma chamada pra cada uma delas. Sem mudar quase nada no seu programa, isso é facilmente resolvível com um `for`:

```
criar_tabelas = [
    "SET NAMES utf8",
    "CREATE DATABASE jogoteca",
    "USE jogoteca",
    """CREATE TABLE jogo (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      nome varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      categoria varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      console varchar(20) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
    """,
    """CREATE TABLE usuario (
      id varchar(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COLLATE utf8_bin,
      nome varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      senha varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL

    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
    """
]

cursor = conn.cursor()

for comando in criar_tabelas:
    cursor.execute(comando)
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Funcionou direitinho.

Comment: @Padawan_22 se a resposta resolveu, você pode clicar no V verdinho ao lado para marcar como aceita

Answer (score 1):

O erro na query é aqui:

`); ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`
  ^

Você tem um ponto-e-vírgula onde não deveria.

Independente de te alertar o local do erro, respeitosamente sugiro que quando encontrares novos problemas executes a query diretamente no banco e encontre por si só o que está acontecendo de errado.

Comment: Valeu  - como você pode ver  -  o problema que ele estava tendo não era esse erro _ainda_ - mas eu aproveitei que você achou isso e já arrumei na minha resposta também - que explica o que estava acontecendo (do lado do Python)  +1

Answer (score 0):

Você está executando várias inserções então você precisa usar

```
cursor.executemany('select * from jogoteca.usuario')
```

Sugiro você usar assim

```
SQL_COMMAND = "INSERT INTO TABELA (CAMPOVALORA, CAMPOVALORB, CAMPOVALORC) VALUES (%s, %s)"

VALORES = [
  ('VALORA', 'VALORA'),
  ('VALORB', 'VALORB'),
  ('VALORC', 'VALORC')
]
cursor.executemany(SQL_COMMAND, VALORES)
```